# jest test failing in component whilst setting the domain

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

- TypeError: Cannot set property domain of [object Object] which has only a getter

Occurring in this function:

```
componentWillMount(){
    document.domain="moc.com";
    CreditStore.addChangeListener(() => this._getModalErrorList());
}
```

Why?